# Mi código en Laravel 8 explota con una Undefined variable: cliente en la vista

Tags: laravel

Mi código en Laravel 8 explota con una *Undefined variable: cliente* en la vista, no tengo las tablas creada en la bd aún.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Función en el controlador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 public function show($id)
 {
     $clientes=ClienteModel::where('idclientes',$id)->firstorfail();
        
     return  view('clientes.show', compact('clientes'));    
 }
```

La Ruta en mi index.

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">

<a href="{{ Route('clientes.show',$clientes->idclientes) }}" class="btn btn-info">
```

Comment: Te está diciendo que la variable no existe en `index.blade.php` y no en `show.blade.php`. Así que fijate a que url estás accediendo, a que ruta corresponde, a qué controlador/función corresponde la ruta, y qué vista y con qué variables está retornando la función

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si lo intentas de la siguiente manera bro, cambia el return en tu controlador asi, no tengo muy claro para que es la funcion compact():

```
return view('clientes.show')->with([
            'clientes' => $clientes,
        ]);
```

Ya en la vista si usas la variable normal.

Hay una pregunta parecida en ingles bro, donde explican mejor solo debes traducir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412832/laravel-compact-and-with